# Hide or encrypt credentials information in AWS Data pipeline

Tags: amazon-data-pipeline, amazon-kms

I am creating an AWS data-pipeline to copy data from mysql to S3. I have written a shell script which accepts credentials as arguments and creates the pipeline so that my credentials are not exposed in script.
used below bash shell script to create pipeline.

```
unique_id="$(date +'%s')"    
profile="${4}"    
startDate="${1}"    
echo "{\"values\":{\"myS3CopyStartDate\":\"$startDate\",\"myRdsUsername\":\"$2\",\"myRdsPassword\":\"$3\"}}" > mysqlToS3values.json    
sqlpipelineId=`aws datapipeline create-pipeline --name mysqlToS3 --unique-id  mysqlToS3_$unique_id --profile $profile --query '{ID:pipelineId}' --output text`    
validationErrors=`aws datapipeline put-pipeline-definition --pipeline-id $sqlpipelineId --pipeline-definition file://mysqlToS3.json --parameter-objects file://mysqlToS3Parameters.json --parameter-values-uri file://mysqlToS3values.json --query 'validationErrors' --profile $profile` 
aws datapipeline activate-pipeline --pipeline-id $sqlpipelineId --profile $profile
```

However when I fetch pipeline definition through aws cli using
**aws datapipeline get-pipeline-definition --pipeline-id 27163782**,
I get my credentials in plain text in json output.

```
 { "parameters": [...], "objects": [...], "values": { "myS3CopyStartDate": "2018-04-05T10:00:00", "myRdsPassword": "sbc", "myRdsUsername": "ksnck" } }
```

Is there any way to ***encrypt or hide*** the credentials information?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to mask the data in the pipeline definition.

The strategy I have used is to store my secrets in S3 (encrypted with a specific KMS key and using appropriate IAM/bucket permisions). Then, inside my datapipeline step, I use the AWS CLI to read the secret from S3 and pass it to the `mysql` command or whatever.

So instead of having a pipeline parameter like `myRdsPassword` I have:
`"myRdsPasswordFile": "s3://mybucket/secrets/rdspassword"`

Then inside my step I read it with something like:
`PWD=$(aws s3 cp ${myRdsPasswordFile} -)`

You could also have a similar workflow that retrieves the password from [AWS Parameter Store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-paramstore.html) instead of S3.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a way that's built into data pipelines:

You prepend the field with an `*` and it will encrypt the field and hide it visibly like a password form field.

If you're using parameters, then prepend the `*` on both the object field and the corresponding parameter field like so (note - there are three `*` with a parameterized setup; the example below is just a sample - missing required fields just to simplify and illustrate how to handle the encryption through parameters):

```
  ...{
    "*password": "#{*myDbPassword}",
    "name": "DBName",
    "id": "DB",
  },
],
  "parameters": [
    {
      "id": "*myDbPassword",
      "description": "Database password",
      "type": "String"
    }...
```

See more below:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-pipeline-characters.html

Answer (score 0):

You can store RDS Credentials in [AWS Secret Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-secrets-manager-store-distribute-and-rotate-credentials-securely/). You can then retrieve the credentials from SecretManager in the data-pipeline using cloudformation template as described below:

```
Mappings:
  RegionToDatabaseConfig:
    us-west-2:
      CredentialsSecretKey: us-west-2-SECRET_NAME
      # ...
    us-east-1:
      CredentialsSecretKey: us-east-1-SECRET_NAME
      # ...
    eu-west-1:
      CredentialsSecretKey: eu-west-1-SECRET_NAME
      # ...

Resources:
  OurProjectDataPipeline:
    Type: AWS::DataPipeline::Pipeline
    Properties:
      # ...
      PipelineObjects:
        # ...
        # RDS resources
        - Id: PostgresqlDatabase
          Name: Source database to sync data from
          Fields:
            - Key: type
              StringValue: RdsDatabase
            - Key: username
              StringValue:
                !Join
                  - ''
                  - - '{{resolve:secretsmanager:'
                    - !FindInMap
                      - RegionToDatabaseConfig
                      - {Ref: 'AWS::Region'}
                      - CredentialsSecretKey
                    - ':SecretString:username}}'
            - Key: "*password"
              StringValue:
                !Join
                  - ''
                  - - '{{resolve:secretsmanager:'
                    - !FindInMap
                      - RegionToDatabaseConfig
                      - {Ref: 'AWS::Region'}
                      - CredentialsSecretKey
                    - ':SecretString:password}}'
            - Key: jdbcProperties
              StringValue: 'allowMultiQueries=true'
            - Key: rdsInstanceId
              StringValue:
                !FindInMap
                  - RegionToDatabaseConfig
                  - {Ref: 'AWS::Region'}
                  - RDSInstanceId
```